# unable to get lat/lng values from JSON output

Tags: android, json

i have the following JSON response from google maps. I've given two postcodes as the start and destination. It describes the route in the response so that part is working. I'd like to get the longitude and latitude from the response so that i can load the respective map. The problem i'm having is that "northeast" attribute cannot be found, any ideas?

```
02-05 18:50:03.668: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381): response code OK 
02-05 18:50:03.673: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381): {
02-05 18:50:03.673: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):    "routes" : [
02-05 18:50:03.673: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):       {
02-05 18:50:03.673: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):          "bounds" : {
02-05 18:50:03.673: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):             "northeast" : {
02-05 18:50:03.678: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):                "lat" : 53.654430,
02-05 18:50:03.678: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):                "lng" : -1.778250
02-05 18:50:03.678: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):             },
02-05 18:50:03.678: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):             "southwest" : {
02-05 18:50:03.683: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):                "lat" : 53.62041000000001,
02-05 18:50:03.683: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):                "lng" : -1.831710
02-05 18:50:03.683: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):             }
02-05 18:50:03.683: E/*********HelloviewActivity(10381):          },
```

.

```
String jsonOutput = response.toString();
      //  Log.e(TAG,"jsonOutput = " + jsonOutput);

        JSONObject results = null;
        try {

            results = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);


            routes = results.getJSONArray("routes");


            bounds = routes.getJSONObject(0);

            northeast = bounds.getJSONObject("northeast");


             lat = Double.parseDouble((String) northeast.get("lat"));


             lon = Double.parseDouble((String) northeast.get("lng"));

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "lon/lat = "+lon +" "+lat);
```

.

```
02-05 18:50:04.668: W/System.err(10381): org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["northeast"] not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`routes` is an array of (anonymous) objects that *contain* the `bounds` object.

```
anonObject = routes.getJSONObject(0);
bounds = anonObject.getJSONObject("bounds");
```

**Edit:** Also - once you get your `bounds` object; `lat` and `lng` aren't `String`s - they're already `Double`s - you don't do any conversion:

```
lat = bounds.getDouble("lat");
lon = bounds.getDouble("lng");
```